# Is there a way to trigger required validation manually given that nothing is selected from the dropDownList

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, razor, mdbootstrap

I have a razor page application that creates a dropDownList in one of the cshtml pages.

View

```
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedItem, model.Items, new
        {
           @class = "**dropDown**",
        })
        <div class="error">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedItem)
        </div>
```

Model

```
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items{ get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Selected Item field is required.")]
        public int SelectedItem{ get; set; }
```

ELEMENTS that gets populated

```
<select class="dropDown" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Items must be a number." data-val-required="Selected Item field is required." id="SelectedItem" name="SelectedItem"></select>
```

The validation error message shows when a dropdown doesn't have anything selected while the form gets submitted which is the expected behavior.

However, recently I have added a new JavaScript called Material Design Bootstrap to change some of the look of the components.

View

```
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedItem, model.Items, new
        {
           @class = "**select**",
        })
        <div class="error">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedItem)
        </div>
```

ELEMENT that get populated

```
<input class="form-control select-input placeholder-active" type="text" role="listbox" aria-multiselectable="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" readonly="">
```

You can immediately see that MBD applies its custom behavior changing element from **select** to **input**. Due to this, the validation error message doesn't show and the form gets submitted successfully when no value has been selected for the dropdownList. I have manually added **data-val="true"** and **data-val-required="Selected Item field is required."** but that didn't help either.

I can see that when I add 'required'attribute and submit the form, the element gets updated to

```
<input class="form-control select-input placeholder-active input-validation-error" type="text" role="listbox" aria-multiselectable="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" readonly="" required="" data-val="true" data-val-required="Selected Item field is requiredis required." aria-required="true" aria-describedby="-error -error -error -error -error" aria-invalid="true">
```

but still no sign of the validation message.

Is there a manually way to trigger ValidationMessageFor?

Comment: Are you sure MDB supports validation for dropdown?

Comment: It works well in my project. Could you please share more code? Also,what are your nuget package references?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my whole working demo you could check:

_Layout.cshtml:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"]</title>

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.19.1/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
   
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.4/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.19.1/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
    
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@model DropDownDTO
<form method="post">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedItem, Model.Items, new
          {
             @class = "**select**",
          })
    <div class="error">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedItem)
    </div>

    <input type="submit"value="Create" />
</form>
       
@section Scripts
{
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

}
```

HomeController:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var model = new DropDownDTO()
    {
        Items = new List<SelectListItem>() {
        new SelectListItem() { Value = "", Text = "" },  //be sure add null value for the first option...
        new SelectListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "Elementos1" },
        new SelectListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "Elementos2" },
        new SelectListItem() { Value = "3", Text = "Elementos3" }
        }
    };
    return View(model);
}
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(DropDownDTO model)
{
    return View();
}
```